# Prove lower bound of integral

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, functional-analysis

I have a continuous function $h:[a,b]\rightarrow\Bbb C$.

Let
$$M=\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|h(x)|$$
I need to find function $f\in L^2[a,b]$ with: $${||f||}^2=\int_{a}^b|f(x)|^2dx=1$$
such that:
$$ \int_{a}^b|f(x)|^2\cdot|h(x)|^2dx\ge M^2 $$

Comment: in fact you are looking for eqality

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done.  Think about $h(x) = x$.  Then the only way the result can be true is if $f(x) = 0$ for almost every $x < b$.  And since $\{b\}$ is a set of measure zero, that means $f = 0$ a.e.